# Do not have choice to boot lubuntu, go straight to XP

Tags: boot

I have a toshiba M55 with windows XP installed. I partitions a drive F: using EaseUS first. and installed Lubuntu 12 with a iso image disk. During installation I choose F: as the location to install, and also choose 'something else' because I did not have the choice 'along side windows'. When I reboot, it goes straight to XP without any choice as I have on my other machines. Could someone please tell me why and how to fix this?

Comment: "I partitioned a drive F:" makes me think you installed Ubuntu from within Windows using WUBI. **Please edit the question above to clarify.**

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `boot` flag to the Lubuntu partition? If not, use your Live Lubuntu to do that (using GParted).

Comment: Please accept if working.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer the_Seppi. I really appreciate it. I did what you suggest. I got the following: Pre_boot eXecution Environment (PXE) v2.1 97-00 copyright intel. PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable. PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM. Invalid partition table.        I used EaseUS in xp and partition a drive F: using ext4. When I install lubuntu, I did not have choice for install along side xp. only replace and something else. so choose something else.     Do you suggest use boot-repair or reinstall. if reinstall how do I make sure to have the choice of install along side the xp. Thanks